# Hamiltonian associated with a particle under the motion of gravity

Tags: calculus

I'm given that $H(q,p) = {|p|^2\over 2m} + mgq_3$,

where $m$ and $g$ are all constants. Total energy $E$ is also constant.

I am first asked to write down the reduced Hamilton Jacobi equation for the system which I believe is:

${|p|^2\over 2m} + mgq_3 = E$

But then its asked me to use the method of additive seperation to determine a complete solution for the Hamilton-Jacobi equation. I don't know how to do this.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is q_3? Is it the third component of (presumably) 3-dimensional vector $q$? Furthermore, the phrase "q(t) is constant" feels strange - if it is constant, why does it explicitly depends on time?

Comment: q(t) = [q_1(t), q_2(t), q_3(t)]^T, that is where q_3 comes from. And I am not sure, what you have said makes sense though. Is it because its a vector?

Comment: You are saying that $q(t)$ is a constant. Constants usually don't depend on anything, but the notation $q(t)$ implies $q$ depends on time $t$. Assuming that $q$ is the position, how can it be constant? It should evolve according to e.g. Hamilton equations.

Comment: Hmm I agree, I wonder if it was maybe a typo in the question because in part (iii) it goes on to ask the position of the particle q(t) as a function of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the equation you've written is not [Hamilton-Jacobi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation#Mathematical_formulation), but simply a statement of energy conservation:

$$H(q,p) = {|p|^2\over 2m} + mgq_3 = E$$

Hamilton-Jacobi for this system looks like

$${\partial S\over \partial t} + H\left(q, {\partial S \over \partial q}, t\right) = 0$$

which, after expanding $H$, gives

$${\partial S\over \partial t} + {1\over 2m}\left({\partial S \over \partial q_1}^2 + {\partial S \over \partial q_2}^2 + {\partial S \over \partial q_3}^2\right) + mgq_3 = 0$$

Since the energy is constant ($\Leftrightarrow$ $H$ does not depend on time), we set ${\partial S\over \partial t}=-E$ and obtain

$${1\over 2m}\left({\partial S \over \partial q_1}^2 + {\partial S \over \partial q_2}^2 + {\partial S \over \partial q_3}^2\right) + mgq_3 = E$$

Now, grab everything that depends only on $q_i$ and ${\partial S \over \partial q_i}$ into a function that we'll call $S_i$:

$$S_1\left(q_1, {\partial S \over \partial q_1}\right) = {1\over 2m}{\partial S \over \partial q_1}^2$$

$$S_2\left(q_2, {\partial S \over \partial q_2}\right) = {1\over 2m}{\partial S \over \partial q_2}^2$$

$$S_3\left(q_3, {\partial S \over \partial q_3}\right) = {1\over 2m}{\partial S \over \partial q_3}^2 + mgq_3$$

so that

$$S_1+S_2+S_3=E$$

Since $S_i$ depend on different coordinates, they must be constants, so $S_i\left(q_i, {\partial S \over \partial q_i}\right) = C_i$ with $C_1+C_2+C_3=E$, which gives three differential equations. For example, for $i=1$

$${1\over 2m}{\partial S \over \partial q_1}^2 = C_1$$
$${\partial S \over \partial q_1}^2 = 2mC_1$$
$${\partial S \over \partial q_1} = \pm \sqrt{2mC_1}$$

This gives a term $\pm \sqrt{2mC_1} q_1$ to the total expression of $S$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks very similar to something in the notes, I was looking in the wrong place. Very much appreciated. :)